# Python-Flask: When run flask in the terminal on windows, there are always messy words.(with image posted)

Tags: python, flask

As we can see below in the image, every time i run flask, the terminal will output the running result with some messy words in it.So is there any solution to it?

(apologize for my poor understanding of flask)

[windows terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8NWf.jpg)

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what you mean by "messy words"? Do you mean the `[37m` bits?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your terminal. Some of the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are not properly processed. No need to worry if you can't fix it – you are only missing out some pretty coloring.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser yes, characters like that.